# Does the Socratic badge require that questions with votes have a specific lifetime?

Tags: support, bug, badges, asking-days-badges

I see this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291013/1518921, but I noticied in my profile on pt.stackoverflow.com is showed 92/100 (Socrático = Socratic):

[image]

I had 92/100 at some time, so in the last 3 days I asked two new questions (vote > 0)

- [Existe alguma maneira pythônico de fazer "slice" de um array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/265066/3635) - 24 Dec
- [Como comunicar abas com uma extensão/add-on e armazenar as variáveis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/265489/3635) - 27 Dec

Was to have increased to 94/100, but continued 92/100

My question is, to meet the requirements of the `Socratic` badge (on any network site) does the question have to be of any specific age?

Or is this some backend cache that is updated from time to time?

Or is it a bug?

Comment: Closed questions do not count towards the Socratic badge (even if their score is > 0), but your two closed questions have been closed months ago.

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm not counting the closed ones, I know how the "socratic" works. The problem is that I had "92/100", I asked two new questions with "votes > 0" on 2 different days (24 Dec and 27 Dec), it was to have gone up to "94/100", but it's still 92. Got it?

Comment: Yeah, I understand your confusion.

Comment: @Glorfindel What a mess? I did the math manually, it was to be 94/100. I did not make a confusion, unless there is some requirement that I do not know.
The only questions that were closed were closed months ago and I was already with "92/100", the two new questions should only add up.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a mess, but I agree with your calculations (and I double checked SEDE to be sure). Maybe the cronjob that updates those figures hasn't run for a while on [pt.so]; we need a developer to be sure and they are enjoying a well-deserved holiday. I'll add the [bug] tag to increase the chance one of them sees this question.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thank you for understanding! It was what I was imagining! I'll wait. :)